# RegEx match only words with no specific words before and after

Tags: javascript

I'm currently writing a function in Javascript which tags specific words.

I have a Box called <code> ... </code> in which i will be writing JS code. I am to lazy to set all tags for syntax highlighting by myself, so i want to have a function to do that for me.

Example:
<obj>this</obj>.functionName(); <- obj tag will hightlight "this" in a specific color.

But if `"this"` wasn't tagged and occurs like that:

<tab></tab>`this.functionName()`;

I want to tag it, but not the already tagged `"this"`.

Here is my JS code:

```
function hightLight(text, tag, html) {
   var taggedText = ("<" + tag + ">" + text + "</" + tag + ">");
   var oldHTML = "";
   do {
       oldHTML = html;
       html = html.replace(text, taggedText);
   } while(html.localeCompare(oldHTML) != 0);//stop if nothing changed
   return html;
}
```

Comment: So if you have `<tab>this</tab>this.functionName();`, you want to tag only the first `this`?

Comment: I want to Tag every "this" which hasnt been tagged with <obj></obj>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
/this(?!<\/tab>)/
```

It uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/4862-master-javascript-regular-expressions.html?start=3) so it only matches `this` when it is not followed by `</tab>`. You could use it like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(text + "(?!</" + tag + ">)");
```

and

```
html = html.replace(regex, taggedText);
```

Comment: Not sure that's what he wants though.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat I think what he wants is to replace all occurrences of `this` with `<tab>this</tab>` by going through each `this` one by one.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't get it. That's a good solution to the problem then, well done.